# Privacy Implications of Android Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been researching android intents and I have some questions:

- can we say that using intents ALWAYS cause the system to pop up an activity on the main screen so user can choose to either approve the action or cancel it. basically the system does not secretly perform the action and the user is always informed?
- are there any privacy implications of using intents??

Hope I clearly stated my questions!

Thank you,

Comment: "can we say that using intents ALWAYS cause the system to pop up an activity" -- no, because an `Intent` does not have to be used to start an activity. An `Intent` can be used for other purposes. "are there any privacy implications of using intents?" -- please be more specific. As it stands, this is akin to asking if there are privacy implications of using strings or integers.

Comment: Thanx for answering! "are there any privacy implications of using intents?" what I mean is, can an app maliciously use an intent to gain access to private data without the user knowing about it?

Comment: There isn't a yes/no answer for your question. Of course you can access private data using `Intent`s if an app is programmed to give out private data when receiving an `Intent`. The question is too broad to be properly answered here. Stackoverflow is the wrong forum for this question.

Comment: Thank you! I read about intent spoofing and intent hijacking, both attacks are not initiated by the app sending the intent,  and I was wondering if the app sending the intent can initiate attacks to compromise user's privacy!